# Access to document folder of each app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

in the past, i used to connect my iPhone or my iPad on my iMac.
In Xcode Organiser tool i was able to see all installed application and i was able to download document files for each app.

Since Xcode 6, i am not able to do this. I think i have to work with "Device" menu instead of "Organiser" menu. I can see my iPhone or my iPad but i cannot see apps.
I do not see "Use for Developpement" button.

Can anyone explain me how i should do in order to download all application document folders ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add your devices to the developer portal (https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceList.action) and update your provisioning profiles accordingly (which is what the "Use for development" button actually did).

After that things are quite straightforward. By going into the devices window in Xcode and selecting your device, you will get the list of your installed apps. Tapping on the cog icon will give you the options to see and download the app's container (as shown in the screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Okay Thanks. But i cannot see "Message" Application. Is it possible to download sqlite database that contains SMS, MMS and Stuf ?
Same question for voice message box...